# Boa Constructor keeps crashing

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm recently using Boa Constructor to build GUI, and here's my problem:

1. create a new `wx.Frame`
2. add a `wx.Panel`
3. add a `wx.BoxSizer`
4. add a `wx.StaticBox`
5. add a `wx.StaticBoxSizer`

It crashes every single time and I've no idea why? Am I doing something wrong?

**Environment**: win 7 Ultimate 64bit / python 2.7.3(32bit) / wxPython 2.8.12.1 / Boa Constructor 0.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

Boa Constructor always automatically add `wx.StaticBox` into previous `wx.BoxSizer` you created on `wx.Panel`, and you have to remove `wx.StaticBox` from `wx.BoxSizer` before you add `wx.StaticBoxSizer` for `wx.StaticBox`, or the whole program would crash.